# Failed override bootstrap stylesheet

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap webjars (maven dependencies) with my jsp pages, and I tried to override bootstrap stylesheet by creating new stylesheet. But, I can't see any changes, even though I respect the order of stylesheet in jsp pages and I added the new stylesheet to servlet-context. Any idea how to fix this ?

This is the servlet-context :

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/"/>
<resources mapping="/bootstrap/css/**" location="/bootstrap/" />
```

and this the declaration of stylesheets in jsp page :

```
<title>Home</title>
<link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/bootstrap/css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
```

and this is stylesheet I created, it's not complet

```
body {
background-color:lightblue !important;
}

h1{

color:navy  !important ;
margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A then you can apply the same code of css that wrote by you with "!important" of the same page where you want to apply the css ...

```
<html>
   <body>
     <head>
       <style>
          ## YOUR CODE##
       </style>
     </head>
   </body>
</html>
""
```